# HTML + CSS: Buttons are unclickable because of fixed header

Tags: html, css

I made quite a few modifications to a css file of a project and now it appears that all the buttons besides the ones in the header are unclickable. they show up like if they were text.

I am far from advanced in web development so I cannot find a way to debug my error. I am hoping that someone here could see where I messed up:

here is where I made modifications:

```
a.learn_more2{
        display:block;
        font-size:16px;
        color: #fff;
        background:#04042d;            
        height: 36px;
        line-height:26px;
        border-radius:3px;
        text-align:center;
        padding: 7px 7px;       
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-weight: 600;
        transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        }
a.learn_more2:hover{
        background:#222222;
        }
```

and here is the html section of code:

```
<section id="top_content">
        <div class="top_cont_outer">
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="top_cont_inner">
                        
            <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="module-inside">
                            
                            <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-9">
                                
                                    <center>
                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                <h1 style="color: #04042d">
                                    {%  trans 'YOUR INVENTORY,' %}
                                    <p>{%  trans 'CONTROLED. BALANCED. OPTIMIZED.' %}</p>
                                </h1>
                                <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:black;background-color:black">
                    <h3 style="color: #8a8d93">{%  trans 'QUANTITATIVE INVENTORY OPTIMIZATION SOLUTIONS' %}</h3>
                    <br>
                                <h3 style="color: #8a8d93">{%  trans 'Turn your operations data into intelligence.' %}</h3>

                                <h3 style="color: #8a8d93">{%  trans 'Reduce costs, inventory levels and shortages.' %}</h3>
                            <br>
                            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <a href="contact.html" class="learn_more2" style="margin:auto;display:block">{%  trans 'Try for free' %}</a>
                                            
                            <a href="features.html" class="learn_more2" style=" margin:auto;display:block">{%  trans 'Learn more' %}</a>
                    </div>
                       <br>
                            <br>
                            </center>
                                
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
</div>                                                          
</div>                      
</div>  
</div>

            
    </section>
```

UPDATE: an answer suggested that it could be that the buttons are masked by a div tag. there are two pictures supperposed in this section, here is the css code to it:

```
.top_cont_outer {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) ), url(../img/exostock_background_banner.jpg);
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: engrave(100%);
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 60px
}

.top_cont_inner {
  background:linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) ), url(../img/test_transparent-removebg.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative; 
  background-size: cover;
  filter: engrave(100%);
  width: auto;
```

UPDATE 2: Issue identified:

setting header to `fixed` is causing the problem. however, I want it to be fixed, how can I make that work?

```
.header {
    display: table;
    z-index:1000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;

}
```

Comment: yes these are the buttons, with the link, it used to work. they link toward existing pages yes

Comment: I just copy pasted code into single html file (with <style>) and they seem clickable to me. Are you sure, that the problem is exactly there?

Which browser and text editor do you use?

Comment: Also, back up your code before you edit it. Sometimes the approach to fix it, is when you compare these two versions.

Comment: i am using chrome and pycharm. No i am not 100% sure but it is very likely because it worked before making adjustments to ```learn_more2``` and now no more. I have the older version of html but not css, what I did was adding padding and modifying line-height value

Comment: add `pointer-events: none;` to `.top_cont_outer` and `.top_cont_inner` css. If the problem persists. Then the problem is not those two classes

Comment: that's not make the trick sadly

Comment: You added css of header, but there is no element with header class. Try using developer tools in Chrome. You can access them by popping up context menu (right mouse click) and select 'inspect element'. There you can check how big is an element on the screen. However .header has z-index 1000, which means, that it may definitely be before buttons (if it was -1000, then it should be beyond that button.

Comment: If you do not know, how to properly use developer tools, just try to set z-index of that header to -999999, so you can be sure, that it is beyond. If you need to position that header, then you probably have to study, what is positioning in CSS (absolute vs relative position).. 100% height sounds little weird for a header, though.

Comment: thanks, I for sure have a lot to learn

Answer (score 0):

you may face blocks with a transparent background.
increase your stack order

```
button{
   position:relative;
   z-index:3000; // or more than the 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there is a div with transparent background on top of the buttons

Comment: this got downvoted but it could be possible, ```top cont_outer``` contains a background picture as well as top_conter_inner. Is there anything in the structure of the section that could indicate that they are hidden?

Comment: Ye, it may be possible, but still 'maybe' could not be qualified as an answer. I do not waste my reputation on downvoting, but I think, that it is objective.

Comment: This "answer" should be a comment rather than an answer as it does not answer the question, it speculates what the answer might be.